# Detect circles width vision framework on ios11?

Tags: vision, ios11

I need to detect circles in an image.
iOS11 allows to detect and track rectangles but how can we track circles ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen anything like `CIRectangleFeature` for circles.
As a workaround you may use [OpenCV framework](http://opencv.org/releases.html) that has a Hough Circle Transformation.

Pro: it's multi-platform compliant.

Con: you need to embed a large library for one feature.

**Edit**: I tried implementing an objc class `VNDetectCirclesRequest : VNImageBasedRequest`. Unfortunately, those classes have a private implementation and the program crashes with `"-[VNDetectCirclesRequest internalPerformInContext:error:] has not been implemented"`. I have also tried to implement this method, but the parameter `context` is of type `VNRequestPerformingContext` that is private.

See [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html)

Comment: Yes I have done that and it works... but I would like to use multiple libraries... Apple has vision it should have the "basics" to make a vision app without adding a new one !!

Comment: I agree with you, but there is no magic, if it does not exists into iOS...